# Update statement using variable

Tags: php, mysql

It seems my code doesn't show the query after using the edit function of my system and after pressing the save/submit button, Im trying to use the variable passing through the url and using the $_GET to show only the user's own account, I know my code has a conflict around the update statement of Mysql, Please help.

My question is: How do I make the query appear after pressing the save button in the form?

Here is my code:

```
   <?PHP
   include ("dbcon1.php");
```

//GET THE VARIABLE USERNAME THROUGH THE URL

```
   $username=$_GET['username'];

   ?>

   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form method="post">
   <table>
   <?PHP
```

//GETS ONLY THE QUERY DEPENDING ON THE URL (edit2.php?USERNAME=$USERNAME)

```
   $customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo where username='$username'");
   $customerrows=mysql_fetch_array($customerquery);
   ?>
```

//FORM THAT HAS THE USER'S INFORMATION

```
   <tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['fname'];?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['lname'];?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['address'];?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="contactno" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['contactno'];?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['username'];?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?PHP echo $customerrows['password'];?>"></td></tr>
```

//SAVE BUTTON

```
   <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>

   </table>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?PHP
   include('dbcon1.php');
   include('dbcon.php');
```

//SAVE BUTTON WHEN PRESSED, UPDATES THE TABLE

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $username=$_GET['username'];
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $lname=$_POST['lname'];
   $address=$_POST['address'];
   $contactno=$_POST['contactno'];
   $username=$_POST['username'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
```

//UPDATE THE TABLE

```
   mysql_query("update customerinfo set fname='$fname',lname='$lname',address='$address',contactno='$contactno',username='$username',password='$password' where username='$username'");
   header("location:index5.php?username=$username");
   }
   ?>
   <table border='1'>
   <?PHP
   include('dbcon.php');
   include('dbcon1.php');
```

//GET THE VARIABLE USERNAME THROUGH THE URL

```
   $username = $_GET['username'];
```

//SHOW THE USER THAT IS CURRENTLY LOGGED IN
//TABLE OF INFORMATION ABOUT THE USER

```
   $customerquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customerinfo WHERE username  = '$username'");
   while($customerrows=mysqli_fetch_array($customerquery)){
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td>Id</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Contact No</td <td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Edit</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['id'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['fname'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['lname'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['address'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['contactno'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['username'];?></td>
   <td><?PHP echo $customerrows['password'];?></td>
```

//EDIT BUTTON

```
   <td><input type="button" value="edit" onClick="window.location='edit2.php?username=<?php echo $username ?>'"></td>
   </tr>
   <?PHP } ?>
   </table>
   <a href="login1.php">Log-out</a>
```

Comment: Far as I can tell, you've a mix of both `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. Most likely the issue. Those two do not mix.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so sir which is better to use the mysqli or mysql only?

Comment: It's up to you, as long as you sanitize properly; but you can't mix them. What do your DB files look like, are they both using `mysql_*` as SQL functions, or `mysqli_*`?

Comment: @eatmycode Does it redirect you after you press submit? do a `echo mysql_error();` after your query execution to see if it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Your Query has an Error

```
$customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo where username='".$username."' ");
```

AND

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customerinfo SET fname='".$fname."',lname='".$lname."',address='".$address."',contactno='".$contactno."',username='".$username."',password='".$password."' WHERE username='".$username."' ");
```

Comment: No I'm sure that would work, there are plenty more obvious mistakes you could point out instead.

Comment: your have pasted your code randomly , please clear that what you want to ask?

Comment: @zardari thumbs up for you sir my program is working fine now